# Ionic - Modal Animation

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, modal-dialog, ionic3

I have a list of ionic cards that when I click on it a modal is opening. I am trying to change the default animation using `ModalOptions` however, I cannot find the string to give to `enterAnimation`. I have seen in the ionic file that the options are called like:

```
export interface ModalOptions {
  showBackdrop?: boolean;
  enableBackdropDismiss?: boolean;
  enterAnimation?: string;
  leaveAnimation?: string;
  cssClass?: string;
}
```

Is there a list of the animations I can use?

```
const myModalOptions: ModalOptions = {
            enableBackdropDismiss: false,
            enterAnimation: ''
        }

        let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create("ModalNewsPage", {data: news}, myModalOptions);
        profileModal.present();
```

Comment: You can try `md-transition`, `ios-transition` or `wp-transition`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass following below these values for **enteranimation** and **leaveanimation**.

modal-slide-in 
modal-slide-out 
modal-md-slide-in
modal-md-slide-out

Thanks